# How to deploy application with Jboss tools on Openshift v3?

Tags: eclipse, openshift, jboss-tools

These pictures show my web application deployment process with jboss-tools on openshift v3. My reference site is

https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/os3_startusing.html#deploy_app

[image]

[image]

I leave the Context Directory value empty.

[image]

I check Reuse existing repository option.

My wildfly pod is created successfully.

[image]

But deployment of sample web application is failed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no idea which process is missed. How can I deploy web application with eclipse jboss-tools?

### Updated

There is no apps in Wildfly deployment folder. In pod log, I can not see any deployments.

```
[0m[0m08:06:03,846 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[0m[0m08:06:03,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /wildfly/standalone/deployments
```

And in web console terminal, I found that deployments war files are located in inappropriate folder.

```
sh-4.2$ pwd                                                                         
/opt/app-root/src/deploy 
sh-4.2$ ls 
README.md  ROOT.war  ROOT.war.dodeploy  WebContent 

sh-4.2$ pwd
/wildfly/standalone/deployments
sh-4.2$ ls –l 
total 12 -rw-rw-r--. 1 default root 8870 Aug 19  2016 README.txt
```

I think I missed any process to deploy my war project into Wildfly application.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I solved it. See this picture:

[image]